# Updating Pre-Made Charts in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have some pre-made charts in a tab called "summary" and I want it to pull data from a tab called "data". By pre-made, I just inserted scatter charts with titles and axes, and I just want to update the X and Y values. The "data" tab has a bunch of cells linked to another workbook. I've also tried making the charts from scratch, which I have done before, but the code from that file isn't working when I transfer it over to this project.

The indexing of the start date and end date are working fine, and everything works great up until I try to actually update the X and Y values. I get "error 1004 application defined or object defined error"

Here's the code I'm using to update the pre-made charts:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdateCharts()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, flag As Integer, k As Integer, n   As        Integer, w As Integer

Dim enddate As Date
Dim startdate As Date

enddate = Worksheets("Summary").range("A2")
startdate = Worksheets("Summary").range("A3")

i = 1
j = 1
k = 1
n = 1

'Index the column that has the enddate

Do
    If Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, j + 2) = enddate Then
        i = j + 2
        flag = 1
    End If
    j = j + 1
Loop While flag = 0

flag = 0

'Index the column that has the startdate
Do
    If Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, n + 2) = startdate Then
        k = n + 2
        flag = 1
    End If
    n = n + 1
Loop While flag = 0

For w = 1 To Worksheets("summary").ChartObjects.Count
    Worksheets("summary").ChartObjects(w).Name = w
Next w

'Error happens here
Worksheets("summary").ChartObjects(1).SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("data").range(Cells(2, i), Cells(2, k)).Value
Worksheets("summary").ChartObjects(1).SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("data").range(Cells(3, i), Cells(3, k)).Value

End Sub


`
```

Comment: You need to qualify `Cells()` with the worksheet as well: `...Worksheets("data").range(Worksheets("data").Cells(2, i), Worksheets("data").Cells(2, k))...`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! Now I'm getting error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Are you positive the range is a "legal" one?  Before that line, add `Debug.print i & ", " & k`.  What does the [Immediate Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/use-the-immediate-window) show?

Comment: Yup, "i" is 133 and "k" is 135. I am flabbergasted good sir!

Comment: Does [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821680/how-to-assign-xvalues-for-excel-chart-using-vba) help? ("How to assign XValues for excel chart using VBA")

Comment: I just tried adding:      Worksheets("summary").ChartObjects             (1).SeriesCollection.NewSeries               and to no avail! The same error moves up to that line.

Comment: Try `Debug.Print Worksheets("Summary").ChartObjects(1).Name`. Does it output the correct name, or still throw an error? (I'm working "backwards" to find where the error is coming from...)

Comment: I'm getting back the name of the chart, aka "1". I really appreciate you helping me figure this out.

Comment: Just as an update to anyone reading - I fixed it by actually initializing a chart variable and setting that chart variable to the pre-made chart in the worksheet. 

Dim cht as chartobject
set cht = worksheets("summary").chartobjects(1)

with cht.chart
.seriescollection......

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
'Error happens here
Worksheets("summary").ChartObjects(1).SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("data").range(Cells(2, i), Cells(2, k)).Value
Worksheets("summary").ChartObjects(1).SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("data").range(Cells(3, i), Cells(3, k)).Value
```

to

```
'No more error
Worksheets("summary").ChartObjects(1).SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("data").range(Cells(2, i), Cells(2, k))
Worksheets("summary").ChartObjects(1).SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("data").range(Cells(3, i), Cells(3, k))
```

`.XValues` and `.Values` can accept a range, which my changed code provides, or a 1D array. Your code, with `.Value`, provides 2D arrays, which choke `.XValues` and `.Values`.