# How to make VBA repeat creating series for an Excel Graph until the final row of data?

Tags: vba

I am trying to make VBA automatically create graphs based on columns in a set of data. The amount of rows is variable with what data is loaded in.

I just can't get it to properly select the data with the next function as it does work when I fill in the Seriescollection manually.

Thank you for any help

```
Sub generate_PrimaryBubble()
Dim ochartObj As ChartObject
Dim oChart As Chart

Set ochartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=100, Left:=200, Width:=500, Height:=300)
Set oChart = ochartObj.Chart
oChart.ChartType = xlBubble

Set CategoryRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & CStr(FirstRow) & ":B" & CStr(lastrow))
Set ItemEfficiencyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("I" & CStr(FirstRow) & ":I" & CStr(lastrow))
Set TotalUPCRange = ActiveSheet.Range("I" & CStr(FirstRow) & ":I" & CStr(lastrow))

    oChart.SetSourceData Source:=CategoryRange

'SeriesCollection Counting

    Dim i As Long
    lastrow = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    MsgBox "Last Row: " & lastrow & vbNewLine


'SeriesCollection Creation

For i = 2 To lastrow

    oChart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = Range("N" & i)
    oChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = Range("H" & i)
    oChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = Range("B" & i)
    oChart.SeriesCollection(i).BubbleSizes = 1
Next i




'Graph Labels
    oChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True
    oChart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Caption = "Efficiency"
    oChart.Axes(xlValue).HasTitle = True
    oChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Caption = "Total #"

'Variable MaximumScales
    oChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1000000
    oChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
    oChart.Axes(xlPrimary).MaximumScale = 1
    oChart.Axes(xlPrimary).MinimumScale = 0
    oChart.Axes(xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0%"


End Sub
```

Comment: A bit more information might help. Are you getting an error? If so, what is it, and what line is it on?

Comment: It's always on this line
"oChart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = Range("N" & i)"
"Run-time error '1004': Parameter not valid"

And somehow it does create a graph but with 8 values but without the formating and correct name attached to each series

Comment: Try referencing the worksheet that you're using e.g oChart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & i) etc.

Comment: Again the error is at "oChart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = ActiveSheet.Range("N" & i)" with "Run-time error '1004': Parameter not valid"

Thank you for helping me, especially this fast

Comment: This thread seems to be the error that you're having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821680/how-to-assign-xvalues-for-excel-chart-using-vba. The series needs to be added before you can set it's values. Try adding oChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries before the line that gives you an error.

Comment: I put the line "oChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries" before the line with the error on multiple places but I keep on getting the same error. Do I need to add something more? Thank you again I am still trying to understand vba more.

Comment: This is hard to diagnose without actually seeing the data.. is it possible you could upload a sample image of the worksheet so I can try and work through it from the start?

Comment: https://unsee.cc/a41e8b8c/ sorry took a while had to anonymize the data

Comment: going to post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new series within your `for` loop. You need to add a series before you can set it's value and xvalue. You have a `for` loop where you set the value of multiple series; therefore, you will need to create multiple series, which is best done at the start of your `for` loop:

```
Sub generate_PrimaryBubble()
    Dim ochartObj As ChartObject
    Dim oChart As Chart

    Set ochartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Top:=100, Left:=200, Width:=500, Height:=300)
    Set oChart = ochartObj.Chart
    oChart.ChartType = xlBubble

    Set CategoryRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & CStr(FirstRow) & ":B" & CStr(lastrow))
    Set ItemEfficiencyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("I" & CStr(FirstRow) & ":I" & CStr(lastrow))
    Set TotalUPCRange = ActiveSheet.Range("I" & CStr(FirstRow) & ":I" & CStr(lastrow))

    oChart.SetSourceData Source:=CategoryRange

'SeriesCollection Counting

    Dim i As Long
    lastrow = Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    MsgBox "Last Row: " & lastrow & vbNewLine

'SeriesCollection Creation
    For i = 1 To lastrow - 1
        oChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        oChart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = Range("N" & i + 1)
        oChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = Range("H" & i + 1)
        oChart.SeriesCollection(i).Name = Range("B" & i + 1)
        oChart.SeriesCollection(i).BubbleSizes = 1
        Next i

'Graph Labels
        oChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True
        oChart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Caption = "Efficiency"
        oChart.Axes(xlValue).HasTitle = True
        oChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Caption = "Total #"

'Variable MaximumScales
        oChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1000000
        oChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
        oChart.Axes(xlPrimary).MaximumScale = 1
        oChart.Axes(xlPrimary).MinimumScale = 0
        oChart.Axes(xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0%"

End Sub
```

Comment: Cheers lovely that worked. Is there any reason that when I change "For i = 1 To lastrow" to "For i = 2 To lastrow" that it includes extra series without data from the category names from Column B? Also it generated series up to 21. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: I have edited the answer to remove the extra series. This happens because you're using your iterator as an index for your series and your row count, so you need to account for your header row by adding 1 to the row index.

Comment: Yes checked it as answered now. I feel like a complete idiot but what do I exactly adjust and where?

Comment: I adjusted the range of the 'SeriesCollection Creation' loop: changed lastrow to lastrow - 1, and the i in your ranges to i + 1